# Проблема с прогресс баром

Tags: android, java

Имеется класс прогресс бара:

```
public class DownloadBar extends TextView
{
private int mMaxValue = 100;

public DownloadBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
{
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public DownloadBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DownloadBar(Context context)
{
    super(context);
}

public void setMaxValue(int maxValue)
{
    mMaxValue = maxValue;
}

public synchronized void setValue(int value)
{
    this.setText(String.valueOf(value) + "%");

    LayerDrawable background = (LayerDrawable) this.getBackground();

    ClipDrawable barValue = (ClipDrawable) background.getDrawable(1);

    int newClipLevel = (int) (value * 10000 / mMaxValue);
    barValue.setLevel(newClipLevel);

    drawableStateChanged();
}
}
```

В окне имеется кнопка и прогресс бар.
При нажатии на кнопку прячим ее и показываем бар (в onCreate)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    checkAndCreateDirectory("/my_downloads");
    actionBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    downbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(fileURL);
}
```

Через асинхронную задачу идет обновление состояния бара:

```
downbar.setValue(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
```

Но при уходе телефона в спящий режим все "слетает" и при выходе из сна, происходит вызов `onCreate` снова (нафига?), асинхронная задача продолжает работать, файл качается с этим проблем нет, но вот прогресс бар слетает.

Пробовал отслеживать через переменную уход в спящий режим и если при выходе из сна еше идет задача, снова показывал прогресс бар и прятал кнопку, отображение работает, но почему-то в этом случае не обновляется прогресс бар, а просто появляется полоска без текста и обновлений.

Answer (score 2):

В событии ProgressChanged вы ссылаетесь на экземпляр прогрессбара, который уже не существует (тут вы очевидно обрабатываете исключения) после перехода аппарата в сспящий режим, а при разблокировке вызывается onCreate и создаётся новый экземпляр который никак не связан с предыдущим. При этом можно сохранять существующий экземпляр в onSaveState  и потом его извлекать из Bundle в onCreate. Но всё равно мне кажется это не правильно и противоречит всем UI Guidelines. А правильно показывать прогресс диалог или прерывать загрузку во время onDestroy

Comment: Так он должен быть не в диалоге... А на экране.

Comment: добавил вариант в ответ

Comment: У меня загрузка файла. А если юзер сам дисплей вырубит и пойдет кофе пить?

Comment: Ещё раз исправил

Comment: "создаётся новый экземпляр". Да верно. Но прогресс я устанавливаю функцией downbar.setValue(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));, а это небольшое расширение setText с перерисвкой, поэтому я считаю что прогресс должен ставится даже обновленному экземпляру. Разьве это может быть причиной?

Comment: мне почему то кажется что асинхронная задача у вас всё же не работает после выхода из слип-мод. Как вы проверяете это?

Comment: дебагером вывожу в онПрогрессАпдейт.

Answer (score 0):

А почему TextView? 
Пишите прогрессбар, а используете TextView как базовый класс. 
Код задачи покажите.

Очевидно, что при вызове onCreate() снова, ваш TextView заново инициализируется и получает значение по-умолчанию, либо я чего-то не понимаю. Попробуйте с каллбэками активити поэксперементировать.